# jquery image gallery that supports custom thumbnails (filmstrip)

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I am looking for a jQuery image gallery plug-in that supports custom thumbnails (filmstrip). Do you know one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very nice jQuery gallery that also suport custom filmstrip is [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/).

Answer (score 1):

I've not used one personally, however, a simple google search:

> jquery image gallery

Brought up a plethora of results. The first of which being:

http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

You stipulate that you would like 'custom thumbnails'. Can you expand on what you mean by this, and detail any other requirements. It's possible that this narrow down what is suitable, and help us provide a better answer.

Comment: Yes I know there is a ton of image galleries, I would like to know which one support custom thumbnails (filmstrip).  
Custom thumbnails? Typical image gallery consists of the filmstrip (which contains image thumbnails) and main image panel.

Answer (score 0):

[GalleryView 1.0](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview#) plug-in supports custom filmstrip, unfortunately version 2.0 does not anymore.

Example:

```
<div id="gallery_wrap">
    <div id="photos" class="galleryview">
        <div class="panel">
            <img src="/upload/pic/BigPicture1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <img src="/upload/pic/BigPicture2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <ul class="filmstrip">
            <li>
                <img src="/upload/pic/ThumbPicture1.jpg" alt="Effet du soleil" title="Effet du soleil" /></li>
            <li>
                <img src="/upload/pic/ThumbPicture2.jpg" alt="Eden" title="Eden" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

All you have to do is to specify a custom thumbnails in "filmstrip" section.